# Has there been any effort to reach out to Classics departments at universities?

Tags: discussion

I feel like students especially would be fertile ground for raising participation.  As a Classic grads, my experience is that the programs have a good number "mythology geeks" like myself.

Answer (score 3):

There are some on Quora and on Reddit. You can also find some on dedicated forums (or fora for beatniks). I got good discussions with students and professors in both Assyriology and Egyptology in any of the formers and they are generally quite accessible persons and completely enthusiasts about people like me (ie self taught internet guys learning on the books/articles they are writing). So there should be some here. Twas anyway my thought when I first joined. Fact is there is no. Even if they are on Quora, Reddit, forums, usenet, and accessible via email a little bit like "Hello Gibet here, random internet guy #1 584 325, here is my translation of this text XX found there on YY with comments on what is a mystery for me. plzhalp. thxb". 
So they should be here. But still, they are not here. Considering people are free to join. Free to post. This site answer pretty well on Google, or Bing or DuckDuckGo. The logical thing is: they are choosing on their own free will to not come.